# How to go about getting raw data from turtlebot kinect sensor?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to create a program that will have a turtlebot map a given area.  However, I am very new to this.  I understand that the turtlebots publish some kind of point cloud as sensed by the kinect, but I don't understand exactly how to subscribe to this data, and what type it is so that I can work with it to create a map.

Anyone have any suggestions or know any good tutorials that could help me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120526/how-to-go-about-getting-raw-data-from-turtlebot-kinect-sensor?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Subscribing to a topic is explained in the [Publisher/Subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) Tutorial.

To subscribe to the Kinect you have to adapt the type and name of the topic.

One way to get information about the data the Kinect node is publishing is to type

```
$ rostopic list
```

in your terminal. This outputs a list of topics that are currently active on your machine. With

```
rostopic info <topic name>
```

You get more information about this topic. There you can also find the message type of this topic. With

```
rosmsg show <message name>
```

You get detailed information about the data structure of this message type.

I hope this helps you a little bit.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-01-30**:
Ok, thank you!